# undefined is not a function (evaluating 'react DevTools.connect DevTools')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i am actually learning the navigation tools with react-native . I tried an example from the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html . I don't know why it showing me this error

[image]

Here is the code :

```
     import React from 'react';
    import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
    import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, StackActions, 
    NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified 
    in package.json

     class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' 
       }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
       title="Go to Details"
       onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Details' })
          ],
        }))
      }}
            />
          </View>
         );
         }  
          }

  class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' 
    }}>
    <Text>Details Screen</Text>
  </View>
  );
 }  
 }

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
Home: {
 screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  Details: {
  screen: DetailsScreen,
 },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
 });

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Have you any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac with React-Native 0.57.8, I deleted the node_modules and package.lock.json and then placed: `react-devtools-core@3.4.2` under devDependencies. Ran `npm install`, `react-native run-ios` and it worked. According to the contributor of React DevTools, this issue has been fixed, based on this thread: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22865

Answer (score 0):

Solved here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22863

Rolling back to react-devtools-core@3.4.2 worked for me:

yarn add --dev react-devtools-core@3.4.3
or
npm install --save-dev react-devtools-core@3.4.3